# How can I make three circles on the face of this rectangle?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

How can I make three circles on the face of the following rectangle?

[image]

I am new to Blender and am still trying to figure out how to use all these tools to the fullest.

[image]

Comment: Suggest you watch a few videos on modelling! A quick one selected at random [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8520lYALOk).

Comment: @JohnEason: but only if you make sound off 

Comment: @Chris You don't like the English accent? :^)

Comment: @JohnEason: uhm...well...in videos like this i am very happy that i can accelerate the youtube speed to 2 .... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

Add a curve circle, size and place it as you need it. Double it two times and move it, and then select all circles, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join. Then select circle, shift-select plane (or your object), tab (edit mode), <kbd>F3</kbd> → knife project.

Delete the circles, select your object, edit mode (tab) → extrude.

[image]

Comment: Very helpful thank you!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Enable [`LoopTools`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gvbz.gif) via menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Add-ons* → *LoopTools*:

[image]

Model using these steps illustrated in this GIF image and use right-click → *LoopTools* → *Circle* to form a circular mesh which you can then extrude.

[image]

Second take with better quad topology and reduced faces. Well, I could have increased the hole radius a bit, but you get the idea.

[image]

Comment: How did you select all the subdivisions? What keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie +1 That's how I would have done it - with the only difference that you could do it with a lot less faces. Just split the cuboid in three segments with loop cut Ctrl+R set to 2 cuts, then select three faces on one side, inset them individually and subdivide only those. Creates less polygons and simpler geometry, might be better depending on what you want to do with it afterwards or how complex the scene you want to use the object in will be.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thank u! yeah definitely better with less. my thoughts were not to have any n-gons. wouldnt that prodice n-gons?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks for mentioning that, why didnt i think of doing insets, ofcourse insets! haha but the subdivions in the inset face would contain n-gons?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Sure, but for this simple geometry the contemplated "fear of n-gons" by many people is often exaggerated and in this case unnecessary and the n-gons also make a more tidy mesh.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann true! good to know!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i noticed that if i only subdivide the face where i want the circles, i cant apply a subdivision modifier due to the n-gon. so probably the latest screenshot i added in my post is the best that can be done?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie That depends on what you mean with you "can't apply a subdivision modifier". You can always do that, the question is what you want it to look like and how it then does. Main problem with the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier often is you need supporting cuts to make sure some edges are not rounded too much, and n-gons can't be loop cut which is a problem. But take a mesh primitive object like a cylinder with n-gons as top and bottom faces. Inset those n-gons a bit, make supporting loop cuts around the body and voilà, perfectly smooth subdivision despite the n-gons in the center.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie You know, in the end it all depends on things you might have to consider before you use this or that method - there is no general workflow you can use for each and every project, no matter what the result should be. In this case it's like, do you want to model it easy and quick, how detailed should it be in the end. Is it low poly style or do you need a low poly count? If I for example new beforehand I will have to use a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier on it, I would perhaps model it like that and still have less polygons then the screenshot above, but very smooth edges:

Comment: Not enough space here for long comments... but actually is this site not to encourage people to chat in the comments anyway. So here is the link to my solution for smoothed edges, left side the mesh, right side the smoothed version: [traffic lights](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O3fBSwv7lqHlKuU1nwj05pWLXwrG8kQJ/view?usp=sharing). Still lots of n-gons, but no problem.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hey thank you so much for your input and enlightening me! highly appreciate the time and effort to share your wisdom Gordon :)